# Inkscape - set perspective on filter

Tags: inkscape, filter, perspective

Is it possible to modify object with texture generated by filter on it to make this texture follow modification?

Simply changing path gives me this efect:

[image: Wrong]

As you see the square has changed, but texture is static. I need to reach this (made with GIMP):

[image: Right]

The second one has now bended the texture. Is it even possible to do this without non-vector image and if so, how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to apply perspective on filters because perspective can only be applied on an object which is a path, but filters are feature of SVG that allow an SVG viewer to change the presentation of an object. Whereas in GIMP, the perspective tool is used to change the perspective of the **active layer content**, of a selection content (means perspective can even be applied on filters) or of a path.

The only workaround is to convert filtered object to a path- https://superuser.com/questions/610585/inkscape-converting-object-with-filter-to-plain-object. 
But this is complex after tracing the bitmap object as it has number of paths in different shades which when combined (as the paths cannot be grouped for applying perspective) gives an object with single color.[image: traced image with 75 paths]
This is a traced object which has 75 paths when combined is a single object in red color.
But perspective can be applied on a single path of the traced object.